# Limiting google directory groups APIs to caller's own groups

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-groups

We are doing a web app for our internal organization use. We need to check members and their roles for a particular group from our backend. Our google administrators are not providing us domain wide access to google admin APIs, mentioning it would be a security loop hole.

We would like to fetch the members and their roles only for the group(s) in which the authenticated user or service account is owner/manager. Is it possible without domain wide access?

Alternatively, in web front end is it possible to check a google logged in user's membership and role to a particular google group?

If there are other possible solutions or advice for our google admin, would be really appreciated.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/

Get a list of the users groups.
if group member role == owner/manager
get the list of group members.

you can also just get the role.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/role

Comment: Can we use google app scripts to completely independent web apps, deployed on non-google servers/cloud?

Comment: I would assume so. Unfortunately I do most of my work on Google Apps Scripts so not too sure about external app usage but it should just require Oauth. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web this might help also https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external#make_requests_to_services_with_oauth