# Google API: list the groups the logged-in user belongs to

Tags: google-api, google-groups-api

i have created an oauth2 workflow that correctly logs me in.

my scopes are:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/groups
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

when i go through the authorization process, it lists
"View and manage your Google Groups"
which i would assume means i can get a list of the google groups i am a part of. however, i cannot figure out where to send a request to get this info.

sending a GET request to the `/admin/directory/v1/groups?userKey=userkey` endpoint returns a `403 insufficient scope`.
but if i add to the scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly

and then hit the same endpoint, i receive a `403 not authorized` because i am not an admin on this system. (nor should i be)

I need to be able to get the list of groups for the user during the login process, not just if the logged in user is admin. This appears to be possible via an Apps Script library that has a read only accessor for Groups Service. I need an equivalent api endpoint. Does this exist? I cannot seem to find any documentation for any groups access outside of the admin sdk.

also, if i hit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/groups?userKey=userkey
i just get the response "groups"
so that's nice...

related/maybe duplicate of:

- [Limiting google directory groups APIs to caller's own groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524405/limiting-google-directory-groups-apis-to-callers-own-groups)

but the suggestion here points to App Script, not api

Comment: I have similar issue. endpoint for admin view groups is working, since i am checking that email address belongs to owned domain, e.g. `test@example.org` has domain `example.org`. Problem is that some users cannot pass authorization_token. I think it is related to those users not being admins on domain I use.

Comment: Also, to answer that question for groups endpoint, it is this one https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?userKey={}&key={}, where key is API secret.